# How to include SimpleXmlElement class from php libxml in composer require field?

Tags: composer-php

This is my composer.json file:

```
{
    "name": "******",
    "description": "*****",
    "license": "****",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "****",
            "email": "****@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {
        "php":">=5.0.1",
        "lib-libxml":">=2.9.2"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "****\\": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

The class included has this

```
class ****
{

    protected $element;


    /**
     * Contstruct XML.
     */

    public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->element = new SimpleXmlElement('<ADF/>');
    }
...
```

And the test run results is this

> Fatal error: Class *****\SimpleXmlElement' not found

As stated here https://getcomposer.org/doc/02-libraries.md. What have I missed, and how can I fix it?

If I remove the require entries (php and lib-libxml), the result is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Add a backslash at the beginning of SimpleXmlElement; this will ensure that PHP doesn't check your source folder for the SimpleXmlElement class:

```
$this->element = new \SimpleXmlElement('<ADF/>');
```

[Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.faq.php#language.namespaces.faq.globalclass)